# Documenting a gRPC API

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, documentation

One can document a REST API with OpenAPI. Is there a similarly clean and standardized way of documenting gRPC APIs? E.g. specify what values an endpoint is expecting, what the return values mean, etc. The service definitions in a `.proto` file do not suffice as documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this: https://gendocu.com/
which let you try your APIs and document the fields. Also generates code for different languages. The project looks promising.